# Bind additional properties at instantiation

Tags: javascript, class, bind

Let's say I have a class.

```
class Room {
    constructor() {
        this.width = 100
        this.height = 200 
    }
}
```

I would like to bind additional properties to it at instantiation.

```
new Room.bind({ capacity: 5 })()
```

Is this possible? (without doing it through arguments)

Comment: As in add extra properties to the object or partially apply arguments?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @vlaz Yes, add extra properties to the object.

Comment: @skyboyer here's what I was trying to get to work: https://jsfiddle.net/0kt9m5dg/2/

Comment: Well, it's not possible to do it throubh `bind` but you can always just directly attach properties to any object `r = new Room(); r.capacity = 5`. There is also stuff like mixins that can formalise these. This seems a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: After seeing the code, you're *definitely* going about this the wrong way. The *consumer* is supposed to know and implement the internals of `Item` in order to even construct it. This is backwards.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, because `new X` returns an object and not a function.

[`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) works with functions only and returns a function.

To get you code running, you could separate `Item` and use the instance for adding this to `item_list`.

```js
class Room {
    constructor() {
        this.item_list = [];
        this.add = {
            item: (item) => this.item_list.push(new Item(item))
        };
    }
}

class Item {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let room = new Room();
room.add.item('bed');

console.log(room);
```

Comment: you can still call `new` with a function and get an object, though. `new` will execute the function as a constructor and return the `this` of it. `new (SomeConstructor.bind())` is valid thing to call, since `SomeConstructor.bind()` does return a function that will be used as a constructor. You do need the brackets, otherwise the interpreter will try to construct using `SomeConstructor.bind` - the actual `bind` method.

Comment: you are right. but `SomeConstructor` is no constructor, but `SomeConstructor.bind()`needs to return a constructor.

Comment: Any function can be used as a constructor `new` will create an object, run it through the function to be (potentially) modified and assign the prototype to the one from the function. At any rate, since `f.bind()` return a function, then it can be constructed using `new`. Whether or not that makes sense is a different matter but it's allowed.

Comment: Absolutely it gets lost. You *can* use it to partially apply arguments, though, since you don't need to care what you pass as `this`. But I'm having trouble understanding what does OP actually try to do.

Comment: @VLAZ here's what I was trying to get to work: https://jsfiddle.net/0kt9m5dg/2/